# Accessing array inside an array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show `images` array in a list but I didn't figured it out yet, can anyone please help me.
This may seem as a repeated question, but I tried other answers, they didn't work.

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 52,
    "name": "viber",
    "images": [
      "7829-hit-the-vibe.gif",
      "8413_Lit.gif",
      "8095_Lazergunzoncam.gif",
      "7090_LaserCamz.gif",
      "2123-vibe-4.gif",
      "3175-vibe-3.gif",
      "7413-vibe-2.gif",
      "1100-vibe.gif",
      "6381-lazeroncamz-2.gif"
    ],
    "download": null,
    "amount": 9
  },
{
    "id": 45,
    "name": "aesthetic",
    "description": "a",
    "slug": "6039-aesthetic",
    "images": [
      "4071_planet.png",
      "3499_love_it.png",
      "3019_space_bottle.png",
      "6033_pixel_flower.png",
      "1620-cupcake-pink.gif",
      "2760-seashell-pink.gif",
      "1794_sparkles.gif",
      "2523_RamSip.png"
    ],
    "download": null,
    "amount": 8
  },
]
```

My code:

```
String jsonString = "myjson";

json1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());

for(int _repeat24 = 0; _repeat24 < (int)(json1.size()); _repeat24++) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray getArray = obj.getJSONArray("images");
    JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(_repeat24);
    Iterator key = objects.keys();
    while (key.hasNext()) {
            String value = key.next();
    }
    
}
```

My task: I'm trying to save the array `images` as json in a key value, example:

```
categoriesMap = new HashMap<>();
categoriesMap.put("name", name);
categoriesMap.put("imagesJson", JSON_I_NEED);
json1.add(categoriesMap);
```

This should work as a loop for all the array positions.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far for accessing the rest of the json

Comment: can you send your full code? it's not enough and I don't know how did you access to that json and please say that json storied in which variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String response = "YOUR JSON ARRAY FROM API RESPONSE";

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

    List<List<String>> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray imagesArray = obj.getJSONArray("images");
        List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < imagesArray.length(); j++) {
            images.add(imagesArray.getString(j));
        }
        imagesList.add(images);
    }
    // Now you have got a list of a list of images
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + imagesList.toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to parse your response :

```
ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
if(response!=null){
    JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i =0; i< mainArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject itemObject = mainArray.optJSONObject(i);
       Data data = new Data();
       data.setName(itemObject.optString("name"));
       ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
       // parsing images array 
        String images = itemObject.optJSONArray("images").toString();

        // this will set images array for each position : ["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"]
        data.setImages(images);
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    
}
```

Now populate your list adapter with this ArrayList you will be able to access images for each position distinctly

To store images for each position :

Create a Data Class like this :

```
class Data {
  int id ; 
  String name; 
  String images;
  int amount; 


 public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImages(){
  return images;
}

public void setImages(String images){
  this.images = images;
}

}
```

Now to access the images in recycler view adapter :

dataList.get(position).getImages(); // ["a.jpg","b.jpg"]

Comment: I updated my json code to understand what i want, can you please check it. Every position must include its own array values, not all arrays of all positions.

Comment: How do you need to show the data in the recycler view if it is position wise you can get it like this for position 0 : if dataList is ArrayList<Data> then dataList.get(0).getImages() and you will get the images for that position . OR you need to show all the images of all positions combined ? I can't understand your exact requirement .

Comment: Your first statement is exactly what I want. I don't want to show them all combined.

Comment: And do you need only the image array for each position or you need other data too like name , id , with it ? I will update my answer accordingly .

Comment: I need the image array for each position and also the other keys like name ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230165/discussion-between-ilyasse-salama-and-medha).